# Nice formatting when sending gmail emails from mutt

Tags: format, gmail, mutt, neomutt

I have been using mutt with my gmail account and recently got told that the emails I send look odd on some devices, particularly mobiles.

e.g.:

```
This is a wrapped sentence, and
it should display in a nice
fashion
but for some reason it does not
when it is received on some devices
I am
hoping that someone can help me with
this.
```

I have `set text_flowed=yes` in my `muttrc`, and compose with `formatoptions+=w` in my vim settings to add a space to the end of each line.

In gmail I can selected 'plain text mode' in the compose window, but can't see anywhere to permanently set this.

After all of this when I compose an email and then send it it still appears badly formatted/not text flowed as above. I've been through various blog posts/SO questions but can't seem to get this to work. Am I missing something or is this not possible? TIA